# Getting specific file which is in use during upgrade/install/uninstall

Tags: wix, windows-installer

is it possible to get the specific file(s) in use, which is preventing windows installer from upgrading/install/unisntall without reboot?

Currently i use `xyz.msi\*vx log.txt`, to debug my created installer (using wix), but this isnt very helpful, cause the only thing you see is:

```
"Detected the application with id XXXX, friendly name 'xyz', service short name 'xyz', of type RmCritical and status 1 holds files[s] in use."
```

The FilesInUseDialog is also not helpful, cause it only shows you the name of the blocking service, not the name of the files in use.
Its annoying to not know which file exactly is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of is to produce a verbose log. There will be 1603 messages in there that name the file that is in use.